# On core swatch selection, redirect to selected color

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1, product-attribute

I have added an identifier in the url when selecting a color using the core swatches magento provides in 1.9.1 for configurable products. Ex. Blue shirt links adds shirt.html?color=blue. I'm wondering if there is a simple way to make the product view page acknowledge the identifier and show the appropriate selected color when loading the product. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is already a core way of doing this.
You have to pass the configurable attribute values like this:

```
product.html#{attribute_id}={option_id}
```

So if your color attribute has the id 99 and the option blue has the id 12 it will look something like this

```
product.html#99=12
```

Here is an example on the demo website: http://demo.magentocommerce.com/men/shirts/plaid-cotton-shirt-482.html#92=17&180=78
This will select color charcoal and size large.
If you only specify http://demo.magentocommerce.com/men/shirts/plaid-cotton-shirt-482.html#92=17 it will select the color only.

The color swatches are linked to the dropdown options so they should work too.

Comment: This seems like a viable option, I'm a little lost how call the attribute id and option id in product-list.js. By default it only products the product color and product id.

Comment: `Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color')->getId()` will get you the id of the attribute. I'll have to check for option id.

Comment: How is it possible to call that within jquery?