# Which version added the core swatch for attributes support via URL hash?

Tags: magento-1, swatches, default-values

The answer of this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/71077/61389 presented a core way to automatically select attributes values using the URL hash.

We are developing a module that will depend on this functionality, and we want to know which version of Magento 1 added it. So we can determine the minimum version of Magento that our module will support and probably provide a backward compatible solution for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** Magento 1.5.

While checking https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/ (which I'm still unable to verify whether it's the official repository of Magento 1). The script [`/js/varien/configurable.js`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.5/js/varien/configurable.js), which adds this feature, has been added since `magento-1.5`.